# Does the Python standard library contain a module for manipulating URIs?

Tags: python, url, string

I'd like to pass a URI to a constructor and get back an object on which I can call obj.type, obj.host, obj.port, etc. The "Request" object of the urllib2 module is close to what I need, but not quite it.

Comment: What do you need that the Request object doesn't do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse)?

> The `urlparse`  module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in Python 3.0.

From the doc:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
>>> o   # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.cwi.nl:80', path='/%7Eguido/Python.html',
    params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.scheme
'http'
>>> o.port
80
>>> o.geturl()
'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
```

Comment: Thanks, this module is precisely what I need.